# 'Paper is used for writing on' or 'Paper is used for writing', which one is grammatically correct?

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis

- *Paper is used for writing on.* or  *Paper is used for writing.*

... which one is grammatically correct ?

- *Chopsticks are used for eating.* or *Chopsticks are used for eating with*?
- *This desk is used for putting the computer*. or *This desk is used for putting the computer on*?

Of the three pairs of sentences, which is/are correct in each case?

Wikipedia [Now at [Prezi](https://prezi.com/p/v3uilsmg8csk/history-of-paper/?frame=a3439b6e37d7668a2b01dc8d49334ecc1427bff1), EA] [a parallel example at [SimpleWikipedia](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper)] includes in a brief introduction about paper

> *Paper, a thin unwoven material made from milled plant fibers, is*
> *primarily used for writing, artwork, and packaging.*

Here *used for writing*, not *writing on*.

However in an English textbook for Junior Three students in China, when it comes to the usage of some objects, an example

> - paper is used for writing on

is given.

So I want to know when a preposition, after an ing-form and possibly a noun phrase in such sentence structures, can be omitted. Why does the textbook give

> - *[The lock] is used for locking the door.*

but not

> - *[The lock] is used for locking the door with*?

Comment: There really is no general rule about this. Grammatically, both are equally fine. It's all down to the meaning. In the chopsticks example, both variants are fine, because both make sense. In the computer example, the first one sounds wrong because it makes no sense. And in the paper example, I can see people arguing either way really.

Comment: As what RegDwigнt said, many people think "with" is optional in this sentence --"Chopstics are used for eating (with)". It is an incorrect sentence -- This desk is used for putting computer.  Here a prep. "on" is need. The two sentences -- "paper is used for writing" and "paper is used for writing on"-- are arguble. But no one gives a clear reason. Why?  Just the language intuition? I'm a  foreign language learner of English. Could you give a reliable evidence? Thank you very much.

Comment: Oliver, you may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Comment: @Reg This has reappeared as a question. Have you a supporting reference, perhaps?

Comment: Maybe consider three versions.  "Paper is used for writing", "Paper is used for writing on", "Paper is used for writing with".  The first one could mean the second one or it could mean the third one.

Comment: @GEdgar But ambiguities are almost the norm in English. Flying planes can be dangerous.

Comment: In _Paper is used for writing on_, the verbal ing-form refers to the actual process, the using of the pen (or equivalent) and blotting paper. With a cuppa at hand. But in _Paper is used for writing_ the ing-form is the more general, more nouny (though not the concrete, 'Whose writing is this on the wall?') sense. 'Have you considered writing as a career?' Perhaps 'in' is the more suitable preposition.